# 3D-view controls missing

Tags: 3d-view, interface

As silly as it sounds, my 3D-view controls are missing. I'm not sure that's what it's called, but its the bottom part of the 3D view where I can select viewmode, layers and object modes.

How can I get it back?

Comment: Probably you have a little "+" symbol on the bottom of the view : drag it up

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is the **Header** of the 3D view - this can happen sometimes if you accidentally click on the top of the header and drag it downwards.

You can bring it back by clicking the little plus icon at the bottom right of the 3D View:

[image: screenie]

Comment: OK I found out what the problem was... I was in some kind of "mode" where the header dissapeared and I couldn't click anywhere outside the 3d-view. Do you have any idea what this setting is?

Comment: Many modal operators enter a kind of blocking mode, where they often display some options in the 3D View header. Pressing escape or right clicking will usually leave the mode.